# How to open encrypted folder

Tags: 14.04, backup, encryption

I have a problem on my Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to back-up my files but they are encrypted. When I try to open a folder it shows

"This location could not be displayed.
You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “...”.
"

Comment: *How* it was encrypt determines how it can be decrypted. Please edit your question and add that information. As it is now, your question is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: If it's encrypted per file, better backup encrypted.

Comment: How do you know that they are encrypted if you do not even have permissions to view the contents of the folder? Are you sure that the folder that you are trying to open is actually _yours_?